# Change product price via tabs related products

Tags: product, price, tabs

in details product page i use easy tabs with related products, now i want when user check checkbox product in tabs change and total price in details page

http://prntscr.com/49e1by

how i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Javascript

1. Store the base product price in a javascript variable or hidden field
2. Create a checkbox onchange event that sum the base price + current selected using element selector to get the related price (jQuery).

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647770/magento-display-price-dynamically-based-on-quantity-tiered-pricing

```
var item_base_price = 0
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  //get base price on page load
  // to do - convert string to number
   item_base_price = jQuery(".topprice_con .price").text()

   // assuming options-18-list will not change or use a different selector
   jQuery('#options-18-list :checkbox').click(function() {
      updateprice();
   });

});


function updateprice(){
   jQuery(' [put selector here] input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
     if(this.checked){
        //to do - convert from string to float
        price = $( "li.item-a" ).parent().find( put relate price selector here ).text()
        item_base_price = item_base_price + price
     });

     //update display price
     //format item_base_price before displaing
    jQuery(".topprice_con .price").html(item_base_price)
}
```

Comment: ok, i have Related products, i have price for replated product, how i can via JS when i check checkbox with current product display base price + price related product, i think this can do in product.js, but maybe have easy way?

Comment: Are you using jQuery JS library? Take a look @ http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031226/jquery-checkbox-change-and-click-event

Comment: i think bad idea use JS library, maybe have solution how price related product add base price product, now my theme overloaded JS and etc...((

Comment: jQuery is easier to learn and most magento installment already include it by some third party extension, but if you think it's a bad idea you can use prototype (which is included in core magento) or pure javascript

Comment: product.js possible change for my solution?

Comment: That would be a bad idea to make changes to a core files. The solution to your issue should be like 10 lines of js code

Comment: ok Man, maybe you can help with JS? i need when we click on checkbox in related products, to basic product price + price related product. can help with code?

Comment: Without seeing your html source, it will be hard to know the best html price element selector

Comment: Take a look at my update

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me, where i can place this code? for tabs i use easytabs and catalogproductrelated.phtml, can i place this you code in this file?

Comment: @R.S why implement a library in a framework that already has one, altering product.js is a viable solution if you extend it using addMethods. Your solution is in no way best practise.